# How do I get the list of all the leads in Marketo?

Tags: rest, marketo

I want to get all leads in Marketo using their REST APIs. Is there a way to do this? I have already tried the getLeadChanges API. However, that only returns leads with changed fields.

Answer (score 5):

Leads in Marketo are assigned lead ids in sequential order starting with 1. Using the [Get Multiple Leads by Filter Type REST API endpoint](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/get-multiple-leads-by-filter-type/), you can query 300 leads by lead id with each call.

You will have to specify id as the filterType and the lead ids as the filterValues with each call to this endpoint. To get all leads, you would iterate through the total number of leads 300 at a time.

The first API call would be (replace ... with all the values in between):

```
/rest/v1/leads.json?filterType=Id&filterValues=1,2,3,...,298,299,300
```

The second API call, and each subsequent API call would follow the same pattern:

```
/rest/v1/leads.json?filterType=Id&filterValues=301,302,303,...,598,599,600
```

Comment: How do I figure out what's the max Id?

Comment: You can get the total count of leads in a Marketo instance through the Marketo UI. You would go to the Lead Database tab, click on System Smart Lists, and then click on All Leads. Unfortunately, total lead count is not accessible through the API. This post has more info: http://developers.marketo.com/blog/get-all-leads-from-the-marketo-rest-api/

Answer (score 2):

By the Marketo REST API, you can request only static lists, and the "All leads" is dynamic.
The easiest way will be:

1. Create a static list
2. Add all existing leads to this list
3. Create a Marketo campaign to add every new lead to this Static list.
4. then just query leads in this list. E.g.: https://%yourSubdomain%.mktorest.com/rest/v1/lists/%listId%/leads.json